# What will be the best way to measure 100m water drill hole for water level

Tags: microcontroller

I have a drill hole of about 82m depth, i tended to be used for pumping house water. From specs, static water level will be at -20m and dynamic (when the pump is running) at -70m.

Which will be the best method to get real time water level with a microcontroller?

The drill itself has some plastic tubes of about 90mma but outer tubes are from steel of about 160mm.

I presume ultrasonic ranging will not work in this tube and/or at this distance. Also the pump has about 76mm so when the water goes bellow pump, it will be a trouble to reflect on water behind.

I think about a pure resistive solution measuring ohmic resistance between a bottom sensor and a top one, but can be hard to calibrate. And will be dependant on water quality.

Another option is to measure pressure difference but top sensor shall be floating at water surface.

Anyhow.. appreciate suggestions!

I would like to have 10cm accuracy on vertical since it will give indications about drill itself over time.

Thank you,

Comment: get a pipe all the way to the bottom. Record the pressure needed to force air out of the pipe, which with 100m head amounts to about 10 bar differential, easy to measure on a commercial silicon differential pressure transducer. High accurayc, relatively resistant to bio-fouling (always a big problem with down-well sensors), and 10 bar is available with cheap air pumps. Drawbacks are it only reads when the air pump is running.

Comment: I would use the air pressure method with semi-rigid tubing extended below min. water height. NSC had pressure sensors, perhaps now TI. Air is pumped in a valve to fill all the pipe with air. The water depth forces the air pressure.  Use 1/2" PVC or PEX-L-PEX. Sensor is above ground.  https://www.ti.com/solution/pressure-transmitter

Comment: Orfruit, what have you already studied? I mean, exactly. What techniques have you already examined and discounted for some reason or another. It would help a lot to know these details.

Comment: Why not use a time of flight sensor, easily serviceable above ground, no additional pipe/pump required, and probably more accurate than a pressure sensing device while there is a pump running.